# Possible reasons for a bigger view count

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Can someone with access to relevant analytics, please shed some light on how the following question got bigger traffic as compared to other posts. 2000+ views in less than 24 hours. We would like the same to happen on other posts as well, so it might be able to learn something from this post.

> [Do projects ever end early?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17721/do-projects-ever-end-early)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was selected to become part of the "Hot Network Questions" panel that exists on all SE sites, which encourages cross-site exploration. I (and many others it seems) spend much time idly browsing the Hot Network Questions to discover new and interesting things.

I don't know what the criteria are for auto-selection to the list, but I think it is based on number of answers without acceptance and number of comments... Or something...

Comment: 4 out of 11 answers were posted by new PM.SE users, which kind-of supports your point.

Comment: More importantly, you can *see* it in the Hot Network Questions list (at the moment)! :)

Comment: Just in case you guys wonder how the formula works... here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/157692